# Glimpse ADO "ExecuteReaderAsync()" does not respond

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, async-await, glimpse

When use Glimpse ADO `ExecuteReaderAsync()` did not return any response forever:

```
var factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "YourConnectionString";
conn.Open();

var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select 1";                 // Correct SQL is not required. If use SQL "Foo" brings same result.

var result = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().Result; // NG. Responce did not return forever.
// var result = cmd.ExecuteReader();          // OK. Responce is return soon.
```

I Use GlimpseAdo, so `factory.CreateConnection()` creates an instance of `GlimpseDbConnection`.
Then I execute SQL async via `GlimpseDbCommand` and wait query result async.

But `cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().Result` did not return any response forever.
Wait over 10 minutes, but not happen timeout.
I paused debug on VisualStudio, debugging statement is on
`var result = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().Result;`.

I think... this probrems caused by async.
Do you know why and where response is gone?

Thanks for your help !


Used:

.Net Framework 4.5.2
Glimpse.Core 1.8.6
Glimpse ADO 1.7.3
SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().Result;
```

Is causing your code to **deadlock**. I'm assuming you're running an app which passes around a synchronization context (UI, ASP.NET, Universal App or such). This is why you [shouldn't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

To get around this, you'll have to make your method `async Task` and use `await` instead of `.Result`:

```
var result = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

You can also see [Trying to call Async method synchronously. It waits on Task.Result forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948818/trying-to-call-async-method-synchronously-it-waits-on-task-result-forever/26948863#26948863) and [deadlock even after using ConfigureAwait(false) in Asp.Net flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588659/deadlock-even-after-using-configureawaitfalse-in-asp-net-flow/25589917#25589917) for more.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I misunderstood about async processing.

Comment: @t2k You're not the first one :)